# How to exclude engine routes from rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an engine (Social Stream) mounted into my Rails app. When I run rake routes I get all the routes, including the mounted engine's routes. This is useful, but there are many routes.

Is there a way to run **rake routes** so it returns the routes for the parent application only and not the engine? I would still want to be able to run for the engine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always found the output of rake routes too verbose. I usually just grep for what I'm interested in.
Say I'm looking for a route that contains the word login, just run:

`rake routes | grep login`

Of course this goes the other way as well. Want every route except the ones containing login? Just run an inverse selection:

`rake routes | grep -v login`

So in your case just do an inverse selection of the engine's name.

Comment: Hi vise, yes I am using the grep method, for example : rake routes | grep media | grep destroy. I was wondering if there is any flag to exclude the mounted routes?

Answer (score 2):

You can also make 'rake routes' show only routes of the specific controller, when calling (as an example for 'homepage' controller)

```
CONTROLLER=homepage rake routes
```